# How to choose which algorithm for Dimensonality Reduction in Python?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset with 300 plus rows and 14 features/columns. I'm trying to classify using a Logistic Regression.

8 of them are categorical in nature. How can I reduce the dimensionality of all these into maximum of 4?

I can use PCA for numerical , but what about categorical?

Also after fitting the model with these reduced values, how should we input the values for prediction?

ie.. if there was no dimensionality reduction, we can input as age, sex, ... But after reduction how can we input these value?

Comment: One-hot encode categorical and run PCA on the resulting dataset. Newly created primary components will be derived from the original variables and if you have values of your original values you can calculate primary components to use as input.

Comment: You can use a fitted instance of your data that you used to calculate PCA to transform your input data.

Comment: Thanks @pavel , but Im a bit confused on inputting the data... do we need to input all the values of features to get a prediction from the model? like age,sex,chestpain etc? but then if thats the case, there we would have to input for all the 14 values right, making the preduction more complex?                                                                     Suppose if I need to predict , how should i input the dataset?

Comment: "...making prediction more complex." More complex as compared to what?

Comment: When you want to predict you'll need to input all variables that were used to fit the PCA. At the same time, the components that are not very useful at explaining variance will get low weighting in the primary component calculation so this will combat the potential overfitting.

Comment: oh! okay thanks mate